# Reading GPIO on imx6 wandboard quad

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arm, gpio

I'm writing a driver to control GPIO pins. I have identified JP4 connector and added a LED on gpio91 (`JP4.06` => `/sys/class/gpio/gpio91`). After reading many tutorials I have written a simple kernel module. This module receives an input from user space and based on input I am setting gpio like `gpio_set_value(91,true)`. Before calling `gpio_set_value`, I am calling one more function i.e `gpio_direction_output`. And thus led is glowing. On the other hand when I am getting other command from user space to get status of PIN (for this I am relying on `gpio_get_value(91)` and for this also setting direction to input), here I am not getting proper value.

Am I missing any step to get desired value? How should I attempt doing this?

Comment: The first things to check for issues like that: 1. Are clocks enabled for your module (GPIO)?  2. Are pins you are using are muxed to GPIO (and not some other module)? Check your device tree file for pin muxes first.

Comment: Also, be sure to call `gpio_request()` (before calling any other GPIO specific functions) and check `dmesg` output: the chances are someone else already uses your GPIO. `gpio_request()` is gonna help you debug this.

Comment: Also, provide us with kernel version you are using and whether it uses board files or device tree for your device. It would be nice to have link to your kernel's git repo as well.

Comment: @SamProtsenko I am not sure how to check clock is enabled or not ,but the our kernel module is happily inserted .even I am not sure my pin are muxed or not however when I am setting the pin the led is lights up.

Comment: @SamProtsenko I am using this kernel version:
_3.10.17-1.0.1-wandboard+ga6e7fc5_

This image is core-image-minimal version.

Comment: So if you can light your LED via sysfs, it means your pin is already muxed. Try to call `gpio_request()` first (in your module) and then look for `dmesg` output, if it says anything about your GPIO.

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/wandboard-org/linux/blob/wandboard_imx_3.10.17_1.0.0_ga/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6qdl-wandboard.dtsi#L390

EIM_D27 is properly muxed as a gpio, its padconf is 0x1B880 which means:

- Slow Slew Rate
- Drive Strength HIZ
- Speed: 100 MHz
- Output is open drain
- Pull/Keeper Enabled
- Pull Enabled
- 100K Ohm Pull Up
- Schmitt trigger input

If you are always reading 1, maybe you could try to remove the pull up by using 0x18880